# Save $_SESSION from a list of checkbox data?

Tags: php

Im trying to save $_SESSION data to keep checked values on page refresh, I have some code written up but I am missing a piece.

**Session Code:**

```
 session_start();
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

   //user posted variable
   $checks = $_POST['personalization_result'];


   if(isset($_POST['personalization_result'])) {   
    $_SESSION['value'] = $_POST['personalization_result']; } 
   else {
    $_SESSION['value'] = '';  
   }
 }
```

**Form Code:**

```
 <form action="" method="post" id="question-form"> 

     <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="1">

       <li>
       <input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="hidden"  class="<?php echo $_SESSION['value']['memory_0'] ?>" value="0"  />
       <input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="personalization_result_memory_0" />
       </li> 

       <li>
       <input name="personalization_result[memory_1]" type="hidden"  class="<?php echo $_SESSION['value']['memory_1'] ?>" value="0"  />
       <input name="personalization_result[memory_1]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="personalization_result_memory_1" />
       </li>

      //There are many checkboxes, this is just two for demo purposes

     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send" />

 </form>
```

For testing I am echoing `$_SESSION['value']['memory_0']` && `$_SESSION['value']['memory_1']`inside the hidden input, they return properly, if the input is checked the class is 1, if it's unchecked the class is 0.

I am not sure the best way to say if it = 1 then echo `checked="checked"`

**My shotty attempt:**

```
<input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="hidden"  class="<?php echo $_SESSION['value']['memory_0'] ?>" value="0"  />
<input name="personalization_result[memory_0]" type="checkbox" value="1" id="personalization_result_memory_0" <?php if($_SESSION['value']['memory_0'] = 1) {echo 'checked="checked"';} ?> />
```

This returns an error "Cannot use a scalar value as an array", that and I dont like how thats written up.

So with all the given information, whats the best way to write if my value = 1 return `checked="checked"`?

Comment: Not to sound like an idiot, but shouldn't that `=` be a `==`?

Comment: No good eye, that actually returns well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make your PHP much cleaner and scalable:

Use this function at the top:

```
session_start();
function checkbox($id)
{
    $isChecked = '';
    if (isset($_SESSION['value']['memory_'.$id]))
    {
        $isChecked =  ($_SESSION['value']["memory_".$id] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    }
    echo '<input name="personalization_result[memory_'.$id.']" type="checkbox" ';
    echo 'value="1" id="personalization_result_memory_'.$id.'" ';
    echo $isChecked.' />';
}
```

and then instead of writing out `<input ... <?php ... ?> ... />` for every single checkbox, just use

```
<?php checkbox(0); ?>
<?php checkbox(1); ?>
```

Comment: I prefer to avoid javascript, when PHP can handle my needs, just incase javascript is disabled.

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry Check out the new answer, it should save you a lot of repetitive code :)

Comment: Hey just saw your answer, thanks for taking the time let me wrap my head around it :)

Comment: The "memory" is also unique similar to the `$id` to turn that into a more dynamic solution would I pass it in the function like `function checkbox($type, $id)`

Comment: at that point, it would be easier to shorten `["memory_".$id]` to just `[$id]`, and then do `<?php checkbox('memory_1'); ?>` since they appear to always be a single string and `<?php checkbox('memory', 1); ?>` is actually longer lol..

Comment: ah ok sound advice, I understand all of this code except how `$id` is generated, I see this alot in plugins and such I could never wrap my head around this which I am sure is simple. I am pretty sure `$id` needs to be declared outside the function? where "memory" is will eventually be filled with a `post_meta` value so I could get that value then add an increment `$i = 0` then `$i++` for the number so like `$id = post_meta_$i` . I apologize if It sounds silly not knowing where `$id` is generated but its the simple stuff that can get me sometimes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35050/discussion-between-asifrc-and-michael-joseph-aubry)

Answer (score 1):

Your short attempt has an error:

instead of `<?php if($_SESSION['value']['memory_0'] = 1)` try `<?php if($_SESSION['value']['memory_0'] == 1)`

Comment: Yeah I just tried that and it works, now is there a better way to clean that up? IDK what about `$somevariable = $_SESSION['value']` then `if($somevariable['memory_0'] == 1)` that cleans it up a bit any suggestions on a cleaner way?

Comment: I would use like this: `<?php echo ($_SESSION['value'] == 1) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>`  It`s way cleaner than a full code =)

Comment: Yeah I have seen this method in plugins, what about `$somevariable = $_SESSION['value'] == 1;` `<?php echo ($somevariable) ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?>` I think thats valid and minimalizes it

Comment: Well, it's way better to understand =)

Comment: yeah I agree, I just streamlined it because I have a lot of checkboxes and makes sense to me to store `$_SESSION['value']` in a variable.. thanks for pointing out the == I never wrapped my head around the difference I need to read up more about the proper use of =